# void or int is not required in main function this programm

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I have inherited **class b1** and **class b2** in **class b3**.

class b1 and class b3 have same functions.

without void or int its compiled but with it giving error

**Too many types in declaration**

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class b1{
    public:
    void display(){
        cout <<"class b1"<<endl;
    }
};


class b2{
    public:
    void display1(){
        cout <<"class b2"<<endl;
    }
};

class b3: public b1,public b2
{
    public:
    void display(){
        cout <<"its base class b3"<<endl;
    }
}

main(){
    b3 h;
    h.display();
    h.b1::display();
    h.b2::display1();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Can you write your code here.

Comment: <iostream.h> is deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Close `;` in last class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using a compiler that has a strange extension. Per C++ standard N3485 3.6.1.2:

> **Main function**
>   3.6.1.2
>   An implementation shall not predefine the **main** function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall
>   have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.** All implementations shall
>   allow both
>   — a function of () returning int and
>   — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int

Besides, your class `b3` should have an ending `;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
main() {
```

C++ requires all functions, including `main`, to have a return type. There no "implicit `int` return type" like in C. Furthermore, `main` only has two possible standard signatures:

```
int main()

// or

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    // same as above, using another commonly found, equivalent syntax:
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

As @taocp mentions your implementation may allow more than that but you still need a return type anyway.

---

Also, you're missing a `;` at the end of the `b3` class definition:

```
class b3: public b1,public b2
{
    public:
    void display(){
        cout <<"its base class b3"<<endl;
    }
}; // <-- here
```

Comment: The second and third signatures you have for `main` are the exact same.

Comment: Which is why I said they are equivalent. ;) I wrote them both only to show the syntax since both are commonly found. But I'll bite and make it clearer.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wondered why say three legal signatures when there are really only two.

Comment: Yeah I guess the wording was unfortunate. Fixed now.